# Product of subsets of a unipotent group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $N$ be a unipotent algebraic group and $X,Y$ be two algebraic subsets of $N$.
It is known that if $X,Y$ are algebraic subgroups of $N$, then the product
$X\cdot Y$ is closed (algebraic subset).

My questions:

1). Is $X\cdot Y$ closed for every closed subsets
$X,Y$ of $N$?

2). Is $X\cdot Y$ closed in the case when only one of $X,Y$ is an algebraic subgroup?

Comment: Both are false even in the additive group $\mathbf{C}^2$. Take $X$ the hyperbola $\{(x,y):xy=1\}$ and $Y$ the closed subgroup $\{(x,y):y=0\}$. Then $X+Y=\{(x,y):y\neq 0\}$ is not closed.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.